# Fetch data from database into react native app

Tags: laravel, react-native, axios, fetch

The API endpoint is working on the browser and on postman, but it's not working with my react native app.
I tried another api example I found on google and it's working but mine is not

Here is my react native code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';
export default Home = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  console.log(data);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
  }, []);
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
      {
      ( <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent:  'space-between'}}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, color: 'green', textAlign: 'center', paddingBottom: 10}}>Users:</Text>
          <FlatList
            data={data.users}
            keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Text>{item.id + '. ' + item.name}</Text>
            )}
          />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? If so please add them to your question

Comment: I don't think this `export default Home = () => {` is a proper way to export a component. Make it either a `const` and export it separate `export default Home` or with a function `export default function Home() {`

Comment: Please provide json content.

Comment: are you sure that it is not a cors authorization issue ?

Comment: how to make sure it's nor a cors authorization issue?

Comment: this is my json content : 
{"users":[{"id":1,"name":"salah"}]}

Answer (score 0):

Fetch in react-native is actually a wrapper around XMLHTTPRequest. I have at times had really strange experiences with Fetch in React-Native and a fix I have found is to use a library to replace it. I use the react-native-blob-util library myself, when fetch stopped working for me due to other libraries I was using.